# Can I use $Permission in a Workflow Rule?

Tags: workflow, custom-permission

I've checked the documentation (and the stack exchange) and have only been able to find references to it being used on:

- Validation Rules
- Visualforce
- Process Builder

Can I also use it on a Workflow Rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `$Permission` global variable in all places where a formula can be used, and specifically in relation to Workflow rules, this means criteria-based Workflow Rules cannot be used - you need to switch to use a formula as entry-criteria

To be complete the same global formula syntax can be used in:

- Formulas used in field updates
- Formula fields
- Process Builder (not a formula, still the resulting metadata will use the same global variable syntax)
- Validation rules
- VisualForce (not a formula, but an expression, still the same syntax to get to the global variable)
- Formulas used as entry-criteria for Workflow rules

Note: this will always be evaluated in the running user's context, which is probably what you are after.

Note2: you can also check for custom permissions in Apex:

```
Boolean permissionGranted = FeatureManagement.checkPermission('api_name_of_permission');
```

`permissionGranted` will then contain `true` or `false` depending on if the running user has the permission in one of its assigned permission sets and/or his profile.

Comment: I don't know why that Idea isn't marked Delivered. The last comment from Salesforce makes it clear that `FeatureManagement.checkPermission()` is the delivery of the idea. That it's in the `FeatureManagement` class rather than in the top-level of `System`, and the perm name is passed as a string param rather than an attribute are trivial implementation details, and calling it a "work-around" is just incorrect. The sample syntax was not a key part of the Idea - the idea was to have a Boolean method or attribute to check if a Custom Perm is enabled for the context user, and that was delivered.

Comment: I'd like to vote this up, as it is true that Custom Perms can be used in workflow entry formulas, which David's answer says they can't. If you edit to remove your admittedly off-topic, and IMO inaccurate, Note 2, I will absolutely do so.

Comment: I accepted it as we can now use it in workflow entry formulas. But I agree with Thomas here, please do remove the "off-topic" or include it in the list of possibilities =D

Comment: thanks for the feedback @ThomasTaylor and Fernando - I've changed the wording on note2 as the Apex feature is very handy and good to have all options documented in one place

Comment: @Thomas-Taylor continuing the off-topic thread - I'd rather see the permissions check being aligned with the use of labels than the current implementation, but agree that might be a matter of taste. I consider permissions like labels as system features, so to be part of system namespace is a better place and the syntactic sugar is a nice to have. Current implementation in `FeatureManagement` does suggest it is tailored to ISVs which I don't think is accurate. Let's leave that discussion for now.

Comment: I agree that putting it in `FeatureMangement` is a little odd. But I know from experience that further votes on that Idea aren't going to change anything. They've delivered the functionality, and there's plenty of other stuff on their list.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of.

You can't use Custom Permissions directly in your Workflow's Entry Criteria. You can, however, reference them in the formulas in your Field Update actions, and you can reference them in formula fields on your object or on the User, which are themselves referenced in the Entry Criteria.

Here's an example of a Custom Permission referenced in the formula for a Field Update action:

[image]

And a construct using a formula field referencing a Custom Permission on the object (here, Account), plus a Workflow Rule entry criterion referencing that formula field.

[image]
[image]

It's important to remember that those formula fields don't count as a change when their calculated values shift, so you can't key a Workflow Rule's entry criteria on "when it's edited to meet conditions" and expect it to fire if you assign a Custom Permission.

Comment: Custom perms can definitely be used in Workflow Entry Criteria Formulas. This may be a change since David wrote this answer, but a quick check didn't find any since-2018-09 release notes to that effect. I would limit their use to rules evaluated on creation or creation and any edit. Though perhaps with other criteria they have use in the "created, and edited to subsequently meet criteria" context.